# Java v1.8 in macOS High Sierra v10.13.6

Tags: java, macos

I was wondering if stackoverflow folks could help me. I installed Java v1.8 on a macOS High Sierra. I also installed Java v1.8 on a macOS Sierra. In Sierra, I'm able to run "java -version". However in High Sierra, it requires that I do a sudo, like so "sudo java -version". How to make it run without the sudo? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install Java? I suspect on High Sierra you installed Java as root, hence the reason for requiring the use of sudo.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I installed it the same way as I did in Sierra.